# Relation does not exist error in Django after postgresql integration

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I used sqlite3 during development, then changed my database settings to postgresql:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'test2',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'aman',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Regardless of any command I write, it gives me the error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "taksist_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...st_category"."id", "taksist_category"."name" FROM "taksist_c...
```

Category model exists inside taksist application. If I take back my database settings to sqlite3, then application runs successfully.

I cannot even run my server. Even if there is a problem with my model taksist/Category, my application should run. Here strange thing is whatever command is written, I got this error. I cannot do makemigrations, migrate, runserver.

What did I do to solve the issue:

- deleted migrations folder, and tried makemigrations
- I created empty    migrations folder with **init**.py inside, and
  tried makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate --fake

none of above worked.

Here is taksist.category model, in case.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Any help of yours is appreciated. thank you in advance.

Comment: checked my model name it is correct everywhere, check INSTALLED_APPS, there is my app name. as I said, if I change my database settings to sqlite3, then everything is working well. I can register new user, and fetch info from database. but after switching to postgreql then this error happens. if there is a typo in my code then it should not work with sqlite3 as well, but it is working with sqlite3

Comment: have you run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: whatever command I execute, I got this error. even runserver, makemigrations and migrate. after change database settings to postgresql, i could not migrate. i can do nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root cause for "relation does not exist" is that migrations have not been run.

However, via the comments:

> whatever command I execute, I got this error. even runserver, makemigrations and migrate. after change database settings to postgresql, i could not migrate. i can do nothing.

That is likely to mean you've written your application in a way that it accesses the database during initialization time, e.g. something like

```
from my_app.models import Blog

default_blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)

def view(...):
```

This means Django will attempt to access the database as soon as that module is imported. If that module gets imported while Django is trying to initialize itself for `migrate`, you get an exception.

You can look at the traceback for your `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError` to figure out what the offending access is and fix it. For instance, the above pattern would be better served by something like a `get_default_blog()` function.

> If I take back my database settings to sqlite3, then application runs successfully.

This bug also means that if you rename or delete your current, working SQLite database, you can't get a new one going either, since attempting to `migrate` it would fail with a similar error. This is not just Postgres's "fault" here.

Comment: wow, thank you for you help. unbelievable approach to solve the problem. when I create taxiprofile model, I used category_choice = [(x.id, x.name) for x in Category.objects.all()]. so as you said It tries to fetch from table that does not exist, because first migration is not done yet. so i modified the code as: category_choice = []. now it worked :)

Comment: That sounds like that field should be a `ForeignKey` to a Category instead, but glad I could help in any case!

Comment: it is already ForeignKey, like this: 
                class TaxiProfile(models.Model):
    category_choice = [(x.id, x.name) for x in Category.objects.all()]
                     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True,  choices=category_choice, blank=True)

Comment: Then you don't need to set choices at all :)

Comment: I mage choices list empty, just to make first migrations successfully. after migrated I took back category_choice = [(x.id, x.name) for x in Category.objects.all()]. after migration it works fine, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

If it' a test DB do a `py manage.py flush`
command, then run the `py manage.py makemigrations`  again, then the `py manage.py migrate` command.

That should resolve.

Comment: same mistake after running flush: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "taksist_category" does not exist
LINE 1: ...st_category"."id", "taksist_category"."name" FROM "taksist_c...
                                                             ^

Comment: when did you get this error, during makemigrations, or during migrate

Comment: makemigrations, migrate, runserver. all. as AKX said, it was not postgresql error. it is logic error. that is in my code I query the model that does not exist yet.